# Nested object state setting

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

I have a problem with setting the state. After clicking the button, the status of all checkboxes should be set according to the initiating state. Unfortunately, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong in setObject method?

Code source: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-saha-6iwjw?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no use of `toggle` in `OwnToggle`:

```
const OwnToggle = props => {
  // not `value`
  const { toggle, path, toggleSwitchHandler } = props;

  return (
    <Toggle checked={toggle} onChange={e => toggleSwitchHandler(path, e)} />
  );
};
```

And you don't pass the state `object`:

```
// not obj
<FirstRow toggle={object} toggleSwitchHandler={toggleSwitchHandler} />
<SecondRow toggle={object} toggleSwitchHandler={toggleSwitchHandler} />
```

Also, you mutating the global object in `toggleSwitchHandler` and then you relay on it:

```
  const toggleSwitchHandler = (path, e) => {
    // is a SHALLOW COPY, you need a deep copy here
    const tempObject = { ...obj };
    // mutate global object
    set(tempObject, path, e.target.checked);
    // relay on global object
    setObject({ ...object, ...tempObject });
  };
```

[image: Edit trusting-visvesvaraya-rqo14]

Comment: That's right! Thank you. But now there is another problem. After a few changes of checkboxes and resetting and then changing one of the checkboxes, several checkboxes change the value. You know why?

Comment: You mutate global object, updated the answer altough I dont have time to fix it

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a const instead of parent state

```
// obj is a const
<FirstRow toggle={obj} toggleSwitchHandler={toggleSwitchHandler} />
<SecondRow toggle={obj} toggleSwitchHandler={toggleSwitchHandler} />
```

Try to pass changing state

```
<FirstRow toggle={object} toggleSwitchHandler={toggleSwitchHandler} />
<SecondRow toggle={object} toggleSwitchHandler={toggleSwitchHandler} />
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the `toggle` which reflects the checking status. but you used `value`, which is never set.

```
import React from "react";
import Toggle from "react-toggle";

const OwnToggle = props => {
  // here you have to use toggle, not value
  const { toggle, path, toggleSwitchHandler } = props;

  return (
    <Toggle checked={toggle} onChange={e => toggleSwitchHandler(path, e)} />
  );
};

export default OwnToggle;
```

And also you had to pass `object` instead of `obj` in App.js.

```
<FirstRow toggle={object} toggleSwitchHandler={toggleSwitchHandler} />
<SecondRow toggle={object} toggleSwitchHandler={toggleSwitchHandler} />
```

There should be a modification in your `toggleSwitchHandler`:

```
const toggleSwitchHandler = (path, e) => {
    const tempObject = { ...object };
    set(tempObject, path, !get(object, path)); // get from lodash
    setObject({ ...object, ...tempObject });
};
```